# Handling XSS false positives in a user-friendly way

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When something that is believed to be an XSS attack is detected, the ASP.NET MVC framework handles it by showing the `/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml` file which simply states "An error occurred while processing your request.".

But this has unintended consequences and false positives and scenario where an innocent user gets thrown an unhelpful error message.

Suppose the user attempted to register an account with the password "`a<b>c`", copy & pasted an email address as "`Bob <bob@example.com>`", or wrote a topic with the subject "`Help me, the car broke down! <important>`".

When the innocent user submits the form he would get an unhelpful error message and have no idea what went wrong and believe there was something wrong with the application.

**Is there any way to handle this in a user-friendly way?**

I cannot put `[AllowHtml]` on every single property in every single view model, or put `[ValidateInput(false)]` on every single action method that handles POST requests, that would totally break down the security and open up for XSS attacks.

Do I have to put a JavaScript that checks for `<` and `>` on every single input element (except those who should allow that) in the entire application?

Comment: How are angle brackets in a password related to XSS? :) You are (hopefully) not printing to the pages anyway.

Comment: @juunas, because the framework checks all incoming data whether they are printed or not.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. But for that one the solution is pretty clear. Just disable the validation for that since you won't be printing it anywhere, and you are probably hashing the password so there is no sql injection possibility also.